# How to solve this integral with dirac delta functions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, dirac-delta

$$F(t)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[e^{-2t^2}\left\{\dot\delta(t-2)\right\}+\delta(t^2-16)\right]\,dt$$
How to get rid of the derivative ? and for the second function i wrote it as $\delta\left\{(t-4)(t+4)\right\}$ and then substitute $t-4=u$ but after that i'm again getting a squared function inside, i don't know how to get rid of it either.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function.  And one does not SOLVE an integral, one evaluates an integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i believe These two will get the job done

> $$\delta(t^{2}-a^{2})= \dfrac{1}{2|a|} \left \{\delta(t-a)+\delta(t+a ) \right \}\tag{1}$$
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t).\delta^{n}(t-t_0)dt=(-1)^{n} \left \{ \dfrac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}x(t)\Big{|}_{t=t_0} \right \}\tag{2}$$

Comment: Thanks Mark it means a lot to me , everyday i learn a lot going through your answers @MarkViola

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

Hints: for any test function $f(t)$,

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\dot{\delta}(t-\tau)dt = -\dot{f}(\tau)
$$  This follows from "integration by parts".  Then,

$$
\delta(g(t)) = \sum_{\tau:g(\tau) = 0}\frac{\delta(t-\tau)}{\vert \dot{g}(\tau)\vert}
$$

Comment: The Dirac Delta is not a function and the symbol $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\dot \delta(t-\tau)\,dt$ is not an integral.

Comment: A tempered distribution it is

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light (+1) for elucidating my comment.

Comment: @MarkViola $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\dot{\delta}(t-\tau)dt$ is 100% standard abuse of notation, particularly in the physics and engineering literature.  I have no issue using it - for me it's just a notation to indicate applying a continuous linear functional.

Comment: Using the notation is fine.  But calling it by something that it is not is objectionable.  The quotations around "integration by parts" mollify this, but I just wanted to point alert the OP.

Comment: I didn't call it anything, and I specifically put quotes around integration by parts because it isn't.  This is clearly a homework problem from an engineering course and I didn't want to launch into a discussion.  I gave correct hints at the level and in the language of the question.

Comment: @icurays1 I approve : in engineering studies (most probable origin of the OP), I have experienced that, for the fast majority of such an audience, by giving too abstract explanations, you loose 90% of them. The remaining 10%, you will find them later on at the top, and it will be time, if they are beginning for example Ph.D. studies to "fill the theoretical gaps".

Comment: @JeanMarie there wouldn't be any need for too abstract explanations nor for abuse of notation if we just introduced Dirac a a functional, taking a function as its argument and yielding the result of said function at a single point.

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes but taking the rigorous definition $\delta:\phi \to \phi(0)$ is unpractical for computational purposes like this one. But I will not enter into this debate: a year or more ago, I fell against my will into a fight between tenants of this school against the other school : it was hideous...